# What is the correct way to attach an Authorization header to an Ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, knockout.js, authorization

I have an ajax GET request I'm firing in a section of Knockout code where I need to ensure the Authorization header is set.

My preference is usually to go with the jQuery shorthand methods like so:

```
$.getJSON("/api/business", function (allData) {
    var mappedOrgs = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new Business(item) });
    self.businesses(mappedOrgs);
});
```

This is fine on its own without any auth requirement but if I need to include the bearer token, I've been trying the more long-winded way:

```
var token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
var headers = {};
if (token) {
    headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/business',
    headers: headers
}).done(function (data) {
    var mappedOrgs = $.map(data, function (item) { return new Business(item) });
    self.businesses(mappedOrgs);
}).fail(function () { console.error('api call failed'); });
```

Even trying to force the issue through the $.ajaxSend() method doesn't yield any results.

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    var token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
    var headers = {};
    if (token) {
        console.info("Found token. Attaching to headers.");
        headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
        settings.headers = headers;
        //console.info(headers);
    }
});
```

So what am I overlooking? I'm checking each request in Fiddler and the Auth header is never attached. There's obviously a right way to do this but I'm missing a step somewhere. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the `sessionStorage.getItem` correctly returns your token?

Comment: Yes. I've checked it in the debugger and in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i use the following:

```
function getListData(url) {
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    cfg.apiLoad();

    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + url,
        type: 'GET',
        headers: { "x-access-token": secure.getToken(), "x-access-finger": finger.getFinger() },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).fail(function(a, b, c) {
        cfg.failError(c);
        d.reject(c);
    }).done(function (r) {
        cfg.apiDone(r);
        d.resolve(r.ListResults);
    });

    return d.promise();
}
```

you can add as many extra headers on there that you wish, ignore the cfg.  stuff, but this is in a network file, as in write once, use everywere with
   `getListData('/api/Name/Endpoint').then(function(r){ '// do something});`

this then solves any issues with having to repeat etc and works like a charm.
my API returns the same model back for any type of results

Comment: Yep. That works. Seems the headers have to be attached directly in the Ajax call and not within an event handler that fires on ajax start events.